# Autodesk Forge BIM 360 API - adding services and activating them

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We are currently looking into automating project setup.
What we want to do is create a new project, add and activate some services but we can´t find the right service types documented anywhere. It seems that the service types in the documentation refers to the old services (Classic BIM360). Do you have calls to activate the new services (Next gen BIM360)?

All the Best,
Henrik
Skanska

Answer (score 1):

Please check the readme of this repo at https://github.com/seb-esser/forge-bim360.project.setup.tool:

or:

```
Service Type    Description 
admin   BIM 360 Project Administration Service
doc_manager BIM 360 Document Management Service
pm  BIM 360 Project Management Service
fng BIM 360 Field Management Service
collab  BIM 360 Design Collaboration Service
cost    BIM 360 Cost Management Service
gng BIM 360 Model Coordination Service
plan    BIM 360 Plan Classic Service
field   BIM 360 Field Classic Service
glue    BIM 360 Glue Classic Service
```

Answer (score 0):

this may not relate to API, are services related to user, or role, or project? in fact, you can see from BIM 360 that specific service have list of members so i assume it's related to member, but how to remove specific service from specific member?